# How to initialize GCP MetricServiceClient with an API_KEY in C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to initialize Google Cloud Metric Service Client (AKA Stackdriver)(Google.Cloud.Monitoring.V3.MetricServiceClient) for a local C# application.

`gcloud auth application-default login` with Application Default Credentials (ADC)(https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) works.
However it is not ideal:

- this leads to expiring credentials and
- also not perfect for building and deploying an application to a client, since need `gcloud` cli command to be run on the machine manually

To my knowledge, using an API key or a service account would be the solutions I am looking for. I generated my API key, but cannot find the required methods to use the API key to initialize the MetricServiceClient.

The example for using an API key with a Google API service is given here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started#simple

Important part of is creating a `DiscoveryService` with a `BaseClientService.Initializer`:

```
var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
  ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
  ApiKey="[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
});
```

Unlike many other Google services, for Metric Service, there is no such constructor expecting the `BaseClientService.Initializer` parameter. `MetricService` class does not even have a constructor, since it is a `static` class.

What is the best way to feed the API key into `MetricServiceClient` creation? Am I missing something simple here?

Thank you!

1. Works: ADC works with default initialization:

```
MetricServiceClient metricServiceClient = MetricServiceClient.Create();
ListMetricDescriptorsRequest request = new ListMetricDescriptorsRequest();
request.ProjectName = new ProjectName(projectId);
request.Filter = "metric.type = starts_with(\"custom.googleapis.com/\")";
var result = metricServiceClient.ListMetricDescriptors(request);
```

2. Does not work: Initializing MetricService with `BaseClientService.Initializer`:

```
BaseClientService.Initializer baseClientService = new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
  ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
  ApiKey = "[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]",
};
MetricService service = new MetricService(baseClientService);
```

Error: `Error CS0712 Cannot create an instance of the static class 'MetricService'`.

Comment: Most Cloud APIs don't support API keys - if the Metric server does, you *can* use an API key by adding a custom header, but I'd be surprised if it did, to be honest. Note that there are two completely different sets of client libraries - the Google.Apis.Xyz libraries are the older generation; you're looking at a newer style; these are generally much better in terms of usability. If you're happy to use a service account, that's very easy to use - see https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/help/client-configuration#specifying-credentials